# the way to get model coefficient after building Lasso using glmnet

Tags: r, regression, glmnet, lasso-regression

After building the `Lasso` model as follows, I would like to get see the model coefficient.

```
fit<-glmnet(as.matrix(x),y,alpha=1)
```

The  `Glmnet` website `http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html` shows the following command. I do not understand the meaning of `s` here. When removing s, the `coef(fit)` will return a matrix, which is not very understandable.

[image]

Comment: the coefficients are computed for a variety/range of values of the penalization parameter (lambda): see `?coef.glmnet`.  If you don't pick one, it will show you the coefficients for all values of `s`/lambda that have been tried.